# how can lightning components in a console communicate with each other

Tags: lightning, service-cloud-console, consoleintegrationtoolkit

We want to migrate / update our Classic Service Cloud console to a lightning console.
We have quite a lot of visualforce pages in our current (classic) console that communicate with each other through the Console Integration Toolkit api. (through the addEventListener and fireEvent methods)

This old integration toolkit api doesn't work anymore in a lightning console.
From what I understand, this has to do with the different domains that VF runs on vs lightning where the console itself runs on. Also, I read somewhere that the old integration toolkit api simply can't be used anymore in a lightning console.

The new similar api : Lightning Console JavaScript API , which also seems to be in pilot, doesn't have methods for addEventListener or fireEvent. Most likely because there the assumption is that lightning application events would be used for communication between different lightning components on the console? Is this the correct assumption?

Also it seems that this new lightning console javascript api can't be used in regular visualforce pages?

Now, what to do then for those existing visualforce pages?
How could I still keep them but use some different mechanism to have them talk to each other?
And how to change those visualforce pages so I'm still able to do things like opening tabs?

Comment: Have you seen this in the Spring 18 release notes? https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring18/release-notes/rn_general_lightning_console_classic_bridge_lex.htm

Comment: I didn't so far. Thanks for pointing this out! Indeed it looks like this will solve our issue. On a sidenote, the Lightning Console JavaScript API doesn't have such methods for firing and listening to events. This is because it's expected that components would talk to each other using application lightning events right?

Comment: tbh I don't know, I've not got that far yet myself.